# script error for elasticsearch Version 1.2.1

Tags: php, elasticsearch, error-handling

I am getting this error when i try to run the script.

```
{"error":"RemoteTransportException[[Fin][inet[/192.168.1.127:9300]][update]]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to execute script]; nested: ScriptException[scripts of type [inline], operation [update] and lang [groovy] are disabled]; ","status":400}
```

I find that in the `elasticsearch.yml`, I have to configure it disable, if I use version 1.4.3 or more, but I am using Elasticsearch Version 1.2.1, where is automatically enabled.

```
script.disable_dynamic: false
```

So how can I fix this issue. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: @Val thanks for editing, it was not working in the elastcsearch version 1.6, so i run the version 1.2.1 but still i am getting the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ES 1.6, you need to use the [following config parameters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting):

```
script.inline: on
script.indexed: on
```

Try it out.

PS: I would not use versions prior to 1.3 anymore. If you can upgrade to 1.6 at a minimum.

Comment: Cool @Val  Thanks a lot :)  for your answer and your suggestion  :)